# protractor not work after iframe was closed

Tags: iframe, webdriver, protractor

I have some test code like this:

```
describe('fancybox directive ', function() {
    var ptor; 
    it('is fancybox click event', function() {

        var fancyContent="<p>Hello</p>";
        var fancyWebsite="http://www.somewebsite.com/"; 
        ptor=protractor.getInstance();
        element(by.model('content')).clear();
        element(by.model('content')).sendKeys(fancyContent);
        browser.actions().click(element.all(by.tagName('button')).get(0)).perform();
        ptor.sleep(2000);
        browser.actions().click(element(by.css('[title="Close"]'))).perform();
        ptor.sleep(2000);
        element(by.model('content')).clear();
        element(by.model('content')).sendKeys(fancyWebside);
        browser.actions().click(element.all(by.tagName('button')).get(2)).perform();
        ptor.sleep(2000);
        driver = ptor.driver;
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.css('[title="Close"]')).click());
        element(by.model('content')).clear(); 
        element(by.model('content')).sendKeys(fancyInline);
        ...

     });
 });
```

after driver switch to iframe and click the "close" button,
the protractor does not continue to run "clear()" and "sendKeys()" methods.
I try to add 
`driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` or  `driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);`
 before
 `element(by.model('content')).clear();`
 it stop working too.

abuot few seconds pass,it keep working to do other directive tests(I'm testing about five directive),
but I can't understand why did it sopt working after switch to iframe,

btw,I got the error message：

```
Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.
```

is there something wrong?
thanks for answer

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.css('[title="Close"]')).click()); This line seems faulty. You need to give the iframe id in driver.switchTo().frame()

Comment: ah..it seems worked. I know that it look weird but it just can click the right button.

Comment: It works even after removing the switchToiframe??

Comment: sorry, i mean `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.css('[title="Close"]'))‌​.click());` can work.

Comment: This is something related to angular/non-angular content on the page. The iframe you switch to uses non-angular apparently. And the initial page consisted of angular content. Did you try following the conventional approach: switchToIframe() -> click -> switchToDefaultContent -> proceed

Comment: The way gives the same error?

Comment: yes,but i think i found the solution! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found that why it timed out.
It seems like @Sakshi Singla said about angular/non-angular problem,
when I run ： `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.css('[title="Close"]')‌​)‌​.click());`
I closed the non-angular frame,then it stocked when it switch to default page because of  Synchronization.
 I add this after I click the close button：
`browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`
The tests now work as expected and never Timed out again.